# Creating or Adding syntax to new file ext in SublimeText 2

Tags: css, less, sublimetext2

I started learning `LESS CSS Preprocessor`  and the files ext is .less, when I view the file in Sublime Text 2 the syntax selected by editor is plain text ... I can change it to css but how to save that setting ?

**// Edit:** Just second after I published the question I find how to save it ... :D

```
View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extensions as ..
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that enables support for less highlighting in ST2. You can get it using the package manager.

If you don't have the package control, you can get it here, it's very useful : http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control

After, just use it -> CTRL+SHIFT+P -> install package -> search for less -> install :)